# Efficient way to remove dups in data frame but determining the row that stays randomly

Tags: r

I'm looking for the most compact and efficient way of looking for dups in a dataframe based on a single variable (user_ID) and randomly keeping one and deleting the others. Been using something like this:

```
dupIDs <- user_db$user_ID[duplicated(user_db$user_ID)]
```

The important part is that I want the user_ID variable to be unique, so whenever there are dups, one should be randomly selected (cannot pick first or last, has to be random). I am looking for a loop-less solution - Thanks!

```
 user_ID, var1, var2
 1        3     4
 1        5     6
 2        7     7
 3        8     8
```

Randomly yielding either:

```
 user_ID, var1, var2
 1       5      6
 2       7      7
 3       8      8
```

or

```
 user_ID, var1, var2
 1       3      4
 2       7      7
 3       8      8
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If the data is duplicate, why does it matter which indistinguishable entity you keep?

Comment: I think the IDs would be duplicated but the rest of the data may not be such as with repeated measures

Comment: Anyway, I would not even worry with the duplicated thing. Just randomly select one entry by ID (`?sample`)

Comment: Ah good point, and my bad to make that clearer. The User_id can be duplicated many times, but the var1, var2 may be different for that same User_id each time. This happens rarely for this project, but I don't want to pick first or last entry arbitrarily, would rather it be selected at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df) # convert to data.table in place

set.seed(1)
# select 1 row randomly for each user_ID
df[df[, .I[sample(.N, 1)], by = user_ID]$V1]
#   user_ID var1 var2
#1:       1    3    4
#2:       2    7    7
#3:       3    8    8

set.seed(4)
df[df[, .I[sample(.N, 1)], by = user_ID]$V1]
#   user_ID var1 var2
#1:       1    5    6
#2:       2    7    7
#3:       3    8    8
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base functions:

```
DF <- 
read.csv(text=
'user_ID,var1,var2
1,3,4
2,7,7
3,8,8
3,6,7
2,5,5
3,5,6
1,5,6')

# sort the data by user_ID
DF <- DF[order(DF$user_ID),]

# create random sub-indexes for each user_ID
subIdx <- unlist(sapply(rle(DF$user_ID)$lengths,FUN=function(l)sample(1:l,l)))

# order again by user_ID then by sub-index
DF <- DF[order(DF$user_ID,subIdx),]

# remove the duplicate
DF <- DF[!duplicated(DF$user_ID),]

> DF
  user_ID var1 var2
7       1    5    6
2       2    7    7
4       3    6    7
```